# Redirected url found was not the final page using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have a html page like below :

..

#### Login
with myPass

..

Using selenium webdriver in Java, I tried the below:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

    String url = "http://www.pic.net.sh/index.html";
    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get(url);

    //driver.click("xpath=//a[contains(@href,'listDetails.do')
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='quickActionHolderInfo loginAccountPass']/a[contains(text(), 'Login')]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='span12 quickActionHolder']/a[@href='/organisation/pass/login']")).click();
```

BUT this page will redirect to another page and subsequent and when I tried the below to find the final redirected url

`System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());`

It will show the url of the immediate page after clicking the link, but NOT the final one.

Have I missed out anything or is my code insufficient to deal with re-direction of the page after a delay in that re-direction? I have qneuired about it here, but to no avail and if anyone can point me to the similar issue, I will be most grateful.

Answer (score -1):

It usually happens due to late call to new URL. There are various ways to handle this:

- Try waiting for some element on final page, then do getCurrentUrl().
- Another way is to apply while loop till the current URL changes.

I use following code for my tests:

```
int i=0;
do{
    try {
    Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    i++;
} while(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("http://www.pic.net.sh/index.html")&&i<10);
```

Either way should work.